# Zebra ZT610: which command accurately reports how many labels in the print queue?

Tags: zpl, sgd

I.e. how many labels left to print in the job?
Made a test label using ^PQ30 in the internal ZT610 label editor.

Shouldn't it then report 30?

~HS doesn't seem to do it, neither does device.jobs.print.

^XA
^LL450
^A0N,39,40^FO85,52^FD43775^FS
(blah blah rest of the label, just text fields like the one above)

^PQ30
^XZ

Comment: can you post the response of the ~HS command?

Comment: Sent this label: ^XA
^A0N,25,34^FO399,258^FD02102^FS
^A0N,25,34^FO519,258^FD50001^FS
^JUS^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ     getting this:030,0,0,0450,001,0,0,0,000,0,0,0
129,0,0,0,1,0,6,0,00000030,1,000
0000,0   Sorry, PQ is actually 30, copied from the wrong place. Sent the labels via Zebra Setup Utilities.

Comment: ^XA
^A0N,25,34^FO399,258^FD02102^FS
^A0N,25,34^FO519,258^FD50001^FS
^JUS^PQ30^XZ

Comment: Does the batch counter in the `~HS` response decrement each time a label is printed/removed from the printer?  Your example shows 30 remaining.